# Using Jquery wrap function with absolute placed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery `wrap` function on an element which is positioned `absolute`. Following is my code.

On clicking the child element I'm wrapping the same with another div , but its not working. Instead the wrapper element appears on the top of the screen. How can I manipulate `css` or `js` to wrap the child element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").click(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #444;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the `wrapper` class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").click(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #444;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
   margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do that, but you would get a result what you did not expect. The reason for that is if you wrap an element around absolutely positioned element, it will become its parent.

I assume you want to add borders to around the child. To do that, you can add them to the parent absolutely positioned as well. For example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var iterator = 1;
  $("#child").click(function() {
  $('#container').prepend(
    $('<div class="wrapper">').css({
      height:(200+iterator*2)+'px',
      width:(200+iterator*2)+'px'})
    );
    $('#container').append('</div>');
    iterator++;
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #444;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green;
  position:absolute;
  margin: auto;
    left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is working well with wrap() function. Add width and height to your wrapper div using css. and it's working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").click(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #444;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green; width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Use append position wrap

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#child").click(function() {
    $('#child').append("<div class='wrapper'></div>")
  });
});
</script>
<style>
    #container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #444;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">

  </div>
</div>
```